# How to search a matrix/array for a subarray containing a specific string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, matrix, sub-array

I have a matrix along the lines of this:

```
const chartypes = [
    ["bad boy","masc"],
    ["celebrity","neut"],
    ["activist","neut"],
    ["expert","neut"],
    ["princess","fem"],
    ["manager","neut"]
//, etc.
];
```

For various complex reasons, I want to sort this array by gender. Thus, create a new array which contains all subarrays containing the string "neut"/"fem" and another new array which contains all subarrays containing the "neut"/"masc" string.

It should result in something like:

```
femtypes = [
    ["celebrity","neut"],
    ["activist","neut"],
    ["expert","neut"],
    ["princess","fem"],
    ["manager","neut"]   
];

masctypes = [
        ["bad boy","masc"],
        ["activist","neut"],
        ["expert","neut"],
        ["manager","neut"]   
    ];
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about this, as I want to return the *whole* subarray, not just the string "neut" itself. Is there a way to do this, or am I going about it wrong? Is this even possible with arrays, or should I have written the whole thing as an object with searchable properties?

I feel like there must be some sort of search using `.contains("fem") || .contains("neut")` that should allow me to at least detect the presence of the string, but then how to go about lassoing the subarray that string is present in remains a mystery.

Have been digging around trying to come up with this answer, and it's proving surprisingly elusive - maybe I'm overlooking something obvious?

I appreciate any insights your experience & wisdom can offer. Thank you.

Comment: The word "sort" means to reorder a list according to some criteria. What you want to do is different.

Answer (score 1):

We can make the dataset you expected with using "filter".

```js
const chartypes = [
    ["bad boy","masc"],
    ["celebrity","neut"],
    ["activist","neut"],
    ["expert","neut"],
    ["princess","fem"],
    ["manager","neut"]
//, etc.
];
femtypes = chartypes.filter((x) => {
    return x[1] === "fem" || x[1] === "neut"; });
masctypes = chartypes.filter((x) => {
    return x[1] === "masc" || x[1] === "neut"; });
console.log(femtypes);
console.log(masctypes);
```

If you want to sort the dataset, just do like below.

```
console.log(femtypes.sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0])));  // first key sort asc 
console.log(femtypes.sort((a, b) => b[0].localeCompare(a[0])));  // first key sort desc
console.log(femtypes.sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]) || a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))); 
                                                         // second key asc, first key asc

// ["activist", "neut"], ["celebrity", "neut"], ["expert", "neut"], ["manager", "neut"], ["princess", "fem"]]
// [["princess", "fem"], ["manager", "neut"], ["expert", "neut"], ["celebrity", "neut"], ["activist", "neut"]]
// [["princess", "fem"], ["activist", "neut"], ["celebrity", "neut"], ["expert", "neut"], ["manager", "neut"]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You really turned this project around for me & I'm looking more into various options with filters now. Searched this for ages & couldn't come up with a solution, but it was so simple! Really appreciate it. Here it is in action, if you're curious: https://croweykid.com/npcgenv2.html <3

Comment: @corvidia My pleasure. I am really glad to hear that :-)  I checked your npc gen. above. That's fun because I love wiz. But the Progress Life button doesn't work now. I am looking forward to further progress of your project.